# Add the requested variables in the query to the rotating hook with WordPress "wp_insert_post"

Tags: php, wordpress

We can add a post with the `wp_insert_post($postarr);` function.

Here, if we add a few data to the "`$postarr`" variable in addition to the information that WordPress needs (just like below).

```
  $postarr = array(
    'post_title'    => 'Hello World',
    'post_content'  => '...',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_author'   => 1,
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'dummy_field'   => 'Dummy Text!'
  );

  wp_insert_post($postarr);
```

If you use the hook just before the content is produced, `add_action('wp_insert_post_data', 'my_function' 10, 2);` returns the data you want.

```
add_action('wp_insert_post_data', 'my_function', 10, 2);

funcion my_function($data, $postarr)
{
  die($postarr->dummy_field); // 'Dummy Text!'
}
```

But after adding the post, we use the hook `add_action('wp_insert_post', 'my_function', 10, 3);` doesn't contain the "dummy" data we need.

```
add_action('wp_insert_post', 'my_function', 10, 3);

funcion my_function($post_ID, $post, $update)
{
  add_post_meta($post_ID, 'dummy_field', $post->dummy_field, true);

  die($post->dummy_field); // "undefined"
}
```

In fact, we can solve this as follows,

```
  $postarr = array(
    'post_title'    => 'Hello World',
    'post_content'  => '...',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_author'   => 1,
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'dummy_field'   => 'Dummy Text!'
  );

  $id = wp_insert_post($postarr);

  is_int($id) ? add_post_meta($id, 'dummy_field', $postarr->dummy_field, true) : "";
```

However, as can be seen from the example, this is a local solution and the following situation will not work, for example when adding content via the REST API or from the ADMIN panel.

My purpose is that when we request POST through the REST API and add a new post, some private data we send within the data becomes available for upload using the ID of the same content, integrated into the WordPress mechanism.

I hope this has an absolute solution.

Comment: Why do you need to have the data inside the `$postarr` array at all?

Comment: Because this method I am trying to achieve will help us both add content and add content with the features we want in a single query. Otherwise, in a REST API query, we must first make a request to add the content, then update that content with the return ID value. Thus, we will have made 2 different requests. @Aioros

Comment: Couldn't it be one request with the post data and the custom data to be added to the meta? Or are we just talking about WordPress's own API?